# FisherFaceRecognizer OpenCV C++ VS2017

Tags: c++, opencv

Using Windows 10, C++, VS2017, OpenCV

As far as I'm aware, I've set up all the files, includes, libraries, etc. correctly. I've followed many tutorials that say it works this way. And everything works correctly until I try to create a `FisherFaceRecognizer`, when VS2017 starts to complain of an unresolved external symbol. Why?

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\face.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace face;

int main()
{
    Ptr<FisherFaceRecognizer> model = FisherFaceRecognizer::create(); // Error here
```

Properties I've added:

- Input Additional Dependencies: opencv_world341d.lib
- Linker: General: Additional Library Directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\x64\vc15\lib
- C/C++: General: Additional Include Directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\include

Error:

> LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: static struct cv::Ptr __cdecl cv::face::FisherFaceRecognizer::create(int,double)" (?create@FisherFaceRecognizer@face@cv@@SA?AU?$Ptr@VFisherFaceRecognizer@face@cv@@@3@HN@Z) referenced in function main   OpenCVProject   C:\Users\Nathan Headley\Desktop\OpenCVProject\OpenCVProject\OpenCVProject.obj   1

Comment: the `FisherFaceRecognizer` is not in `opencv_world341d.lib`, it's in one of the contrib libs `opencv_face341d.lib` presumably